# How to drag a view from showing little to full like dragging the result of Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, drag-and-drop

I want to drag a view from bottom to top which shows more information when I drag the view.The result which I want to achieve is like google map.


Before Dragging:

[image: Before Dragging]

Dragging:Show some more information

[image: Dragging]

After Dragging:Show all information

[image: After Gragging]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to achieve it https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel